# Why is SELECT * WHERE id=1 ORDERBY at LIMIT 1 not executing in O(log n) like simple binary searching?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**ANSWER: It DOES execute in O(log n) like simple binary search**

<s>PREFACE: This should actually be **bug report (for all SQL-database implementations)**, because I found *corner-case* (which is *very common*, which **should be blazing fast**, but is not), and I wanted to make sure. So far it turned out I was correct and the ***query optimizer* is not optimal.**</s>

---

I am complete noob to SQL, but I know how data structures and algorithms work. I was expecting that **finding newest record/event for selected unit/user** must be trivially fast, because database is using B-Tree (index) and that query is very **similar to finding insertion point in sorted array** for record with some unit/user id and maximum time (or id+1,time=0).

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/028f6/1)

Create table and index like this:

```
create table t (
    id int, at time, id2 int
);

create unique index i on t (id, at);
create unique index i2 on t (id2);

insert into t (id, at, id2) values
    (1, '12:00', 1001200),
    (1, '12:30', 1001230),
    (2, '12:00', 2001200),
    (2, '13:00', 2001300);
```

and try these queries:

```
select * from t
where id=1
order by at desc
limit 1;

select * from t
where id2<2000000
order by id2 desc
limit 1
```

When you analyze those two queries, you will find that it first fetches all rows matching the `where` condition (getting multiple rows) and then selects the first one (`limit 1`) **instead of directly searching the one and only record I want** <s>(proved so far, it IS NOT OPTIMAL)</s>. I was searching and asking this whole day and couldn't find any query that would trully do what is needed fast enough.

1. Can it be done by writing proper SQL query? <s>....answer so far: NO</s>
2. Can it be done in principle by optimizing the query *(plan)*? ... answer so far: YES!

My second query illustrates how the optimized search should work:
`id2 = id*10000+at`, *find highest `id2` smaller than some value* (`id2 <= 199999` is the same as `id2 < 2000000` and that works - finding `1001230` which means `id=1, at="12:30"`).

I know how to do that with [binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) (searching for `2000000` will return insertion point which is just after the record I want) and I am sure it can be done with B-Tree, but why is it not possible in SQL? Such useful query!

---

**EDIT - Response to comments:**
Unfortunately I cannot perform the query on real database right now, but the result was exactly the same as in that [SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/028f6/1):

```
Limit (cost=0.15..3.73 rows=1 width=16)  
      -> Index Scan Backward using i on t (cost=0.15..32.31 rows=9 width=16)   
         Index Cond: (id = 1)
```

The only difference is that **max estimated cost** for that "Index Scan Backward" was huge. The query itself was in seconds (well 100ms, depends on ID and how many records are there for the unit). In any case, it should do direct index search, nothing else is faster. I have searched SE (SO+DBA) today for similar examples and all the queries work the same way - Index Scan (possibly bitmap) and FETCH FIRST afterwards.

Comment: Four rows in a table is too small for judging an execution plan.  Postgres has decided that a full table scan is less expensive than using an index, probably because the table has so few rows.

Comment: We did try similar query on production dbase with billions of records. Same result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)` but for a table with real world data. [**Formatted**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Also you are using simple select...that is equal to a trivial plan

Comment: `When you analyze those two queries, you ... ` Your deduction isnt correct.  The optimizer perform exactly how should. First use index to filter using your `where` condition then have to sort because you are using the second field. And last will choose the first element. The advantage of having a composite index is you dont have to look back at the table to get `at`

Comment: Maybe you could use `generate_series` to make a bigger sample.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Look at the second query. I do understand why it could be hard for the optimizer, but can you see that it can be solved faster? The optimizer is not doing good job. I have searched documentation for PostreSQL especially about MAX aggregate and how to create custom aggregates - it specifically states that some such queries can be optimized by using index only.

Comment: "*In any case, it should do direct index search*" - it is doing exactly that: `Index Scan Backward`

Comment: I admint that I am not familiar with that analyze, but that (cost=0.15..32.31) or the second number being huge on real dbase looks like it is doing it in two phases (even the lining in analyze and the result time)

Comment: what you want for us? You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I just say you make and assumption and was wrong.

Comment: btw dont say `'dbase'` because can be confussed with `DBase` rdbms, say db instead.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza You are stating that my assuption is wrong and in the same comment saying that it is correct, that it first filterst then sorts. It should not because it can be done in better way. I want to know if that is trully limitation of SQL, or there is better query. And secondly, I do belive the optimizer can be improved.

Comment: Nope, I say your assumption was wrong when you say `optimizer was doing the wrong thing`.  Optimizer did was was supposed to do. How you think optimizer can `instead of directly searching the one and only record I want.` without follow those steps?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza By "wrong" I mean "not what is fastest" and if by "did what it is supposed to do" you mean that it is not programmed to understand that `limit 1` can be done faster, than I have to read your answer as: yes, that is the limitation of current SQL implementations. Do you agree that the query can be executed a lot fast (if done properly)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130731/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-firda).

Comment: Unless you show us the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` from production this is impossible to answer. If you worry about table names, you can anonymize the plan on http://explain.depesz.com Also: the cost as a "standalon" value is **not** enough to decide if a plan is bad or not

Comment: I will try to paste the analyze tomorrow, but it will not bring anything new, it is just the same. The planner is not able to take advantage of the possible fast-search, because it was not programmed to do so. See the chat. It does what it is supposed to do but that is not optimal and that is my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In any case, it should do direct index search, nothing else is faster.

It does **exactly** that. If you run the explain using `explain (analyze, buffers)` you will see that:

```
Limit  (cost=0.15..1.49 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Index Scan Backward using i on t  (cost=0.15..12.19 rows=9 width=16) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning time: 0.184 ms
Execution time: 0.049 ms
```

(The above was generated with an installation where I adjusted `postgresql.conf` - that's why the cost estimation is lower then in your example)

`Buffers: shared hit=2` means it took Postgres exactly two I/O operations (served from the cache) to get the result - and that is as fast as it gets.

The first I/O operation is to find the row in the index `Index Cond: (id = 1)`. But as the index only contains the ID and the query wants **all** columns from the table the database has to do another I/O operation to get all the columns.

This is one of the reasons why `select *` is considered bad coding style - it gives the planner less choices to get it right.

The only way you can remove the second I/O operation is when you put **all** columns into the index, then you would probably see an `Index Only Scan Backwards` - but with only 4 rows this is unlikely to happen.

With only three columns in the table and all of them in the index it would theoretically be possible to get rid of the table all together and only keep the index. Unfortunately Postgres does not (yet?) support that. This is available in other DBMS. In Oracle for example this is known as an "Index Only Table". Microsoft calls it a "Clustered Index" - if at all this could be the only criticism on how Postgres deals with this kind of queries.

> The only difference is that max estimated cost for that "Index Scan Backward" was huge

First: "32" is not huge at all. It is not even "big". And if you pay close attention to the plan you will see that the cost of the outer node is actually **less** (3.73) then the cost for the inner `Index Scan Backwards` node - because the planner sees the `limit` clause and knows that it will never scan the entire index - it will stop after the first row.

The cost reported for the `Index Scan Backwards` node is the *theoretical* total cost *if* the node needs to be executed completely.

---

From the chat:

> I know that searching for "highest smaller than" in sorted array (and B-tree) is simple and fast - O(log n) - just like finding exact value or insertion point. But when we did try to use SQL the result was useless, lasted too long.

Well, of course a B-Tree search of an in-memory structure using a programming language and without having to take concurrent access and transactions into account **will** be faster. A relational database has to take care of a **lot** more things then a C++ program traversing a B-Tree.

A relational database is not the tool to solve all problems. And if you don't need transactional consistency, concurrency control and all the other things that a relational database (and SQL) offer, then most probably a relational database is not the right tool for you.

> It usually is around 100ms which is not that bad, but sometimes becomes a bottleneck

You need to find out if that query is I/O bound or CPU bound you can do that using `explain (analyze, timing, buffers)`. If it's I/O bound then you might consider using more and faster (=SSD) harddisks. Using high-end SSDs very 
often make a **huge** difference - especially if the data set doesn't fit into memory (which it seems to be in your case if you are talking about 153 billion rows)

---

I filled the sample table with 14 million rows: 10,000 unique IDs and 1400 "at" values for each ID. When I then run the statement to look up a single ID (`where id=1`), the plan doesn't really change:

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..1.23 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: id, at, id2
  Buffers: shared hit=5
  ->  Index Scan Backward using i1 on stuff.t  (cost=0.56..1001.81 rows=1501 width=20) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: id, at, id2
        Index Cond: (t.id = 1)
        Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning time: 0.158 ms
Execution time: 0.054 ms
```

As you can see: compared to the first execution plan that was taken when the table only contained 4 rows, the cost estimation for the `Index Scan Backwards` is a **lot** higher now, but the runtime hasn't changed at all and the cost of the **outer** node is still the same. So do not take the cost of the inner node where a `LIMIT` is applied as the criteria whether the plan is "correct" or not.

I am not sure however, where the 5 shared hits come from. Maybe because the index structure is bigger now.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, I will give that some more time.

Comment: @firda: I also added an execution plan for the query when the table contained 14 million rows to proof that the cost of the inner node isn't relevant to the overal cost or runtime

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe it trully does what I thought it should. It all started with me stating it must be fast and work-mates stating it is not. I am searching, learning and exploring the unknown since then. I have noticed that they got scared whenever seeing big `(cost=...big number)` (cost=0.56..1001.81) in your case. You are now telling me, that it is not what it seems to be.

Comment: @firda: well, you need take the **complete** plan into account - especially if an outer node has a _lower_ cost.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Sounds reasonable and in fact the best outcome I could dream of. I was correct in the first place after all (it should be fast, it can be done and it seems to do it fast, despite what work-mates were telling me). ... But I get it why it got downvoted and consider deleting it completely. What do you think, should it disapear from SO (for being something else than the title states)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's anything particularly wrong, and I would caution you not to call a "bug" in a DBMS anything that produces the correct answer.  At most, there is an optimization opportunity.

I wonder if you have tripped up the optimizer with the pernicious `LIMIT 1` construction.  Does anything change if you use standard SQL?

```
select * from t
where id=1
and at = (select max(at) from t where id = 1);
```

If that works better (or worse!) I would file a problem report with Postgres, because I'd imagine they'd want to know.   (Maybe they already do!)

> proved so far, it IS NOT OPTIMAL

You want to be careful about claims of optimality.  It's measured on the machine, not in the textbooks.

First, you're relying on your interpretation of the DBMS's report.  It could be wrong or misleading, and you could be wrong.

Second, when it comes to DBMS query planning, very little is obvious. There's a least as much unknown as known.  The DBMS cannot know there there are records out there with `id = 2`. Given you want *max(at) and id = 1*, it cannot know that's the same as *at just before the first id = 2*.  It works with what it knows, and it knows a lot you can't, such as: the structure of its index (internally), the state of its cache, the statistical selectivity of the index, the value of RAM cache performance to a linear scan.  It could be using an algorithm that guards against a common worst-case scenario at the expense of seizing on the very best opportunity in this case.

I would not be surprised, for example (I don't know), if their measurements showed 9 in 10 queries sort in ascending order, and so they optimize for that case.  You could think of it as *very* late binding.

You didn't say, but I assume you've already chased down any administrative steps needed to inform the optimizer about data cardinality.  It pays to check all the boxes.

If you think you've done everything possible, and you're convinced there's an optimization opportunity, then I suggest your best option is join their mailing list and post your results.  Possible outcomes:

- shrug, not interesting
- known behavior (for better or worse)
- please try *X*
- thanks, confirmed, todo

At least then you know where you stand, and might find a solution.

> should actually be bug report (for all SQL-database implementations)

Simply, no.  You might *possibly* have discovered a way that Postgres could execute a query like yours faster.  You've discovered nothing about SQL, and nothing about *any* other -- let alone *all* other -- SQL implementations.

Measure twice, cut once.

Comment: I cannot know all implementations, but PostreSQL + MySQL is already quite a set. That query with MAX is the same (the inner query for max). I will definitely keep searching and maybe one day submit some patch.